# Triggered Automation Studio: Data Extension Import Error

Tags: marketing-cloud, import

I am trying to import `data` into Data Extension via Triggered Automation Studio.

I have set up all necessary steps (Import definition, Triggered Automation Studio).
Then, I have uploaded into Exacttarget FTP my input file. Automation Studio has detected new file and started uploading, but it has completed with error...

But, if I go to Email - Data Extension - Records - Import and import manually, everything works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Error message that I've received in my email:

> The following import has been halted Wednesday, June 18, 2014 2:25:38
>   AM CST
>
> Name: probandoCargarDatosCliente    Description: probando Carga rDatos
>   de Cliente    External Key: probandoCargarDatosCliente    Source:
>   new_3.txt     Destination: Datos_cliente
>
> Results:
>
> Inserted: 0     Updated: 0  Duplicate Keys: 0
>
> The following warnings were issued:
>
> Warning: Import aborted in DsvFileSourceReader. One or more errors
>   indicating why the import was aborted may be logged to the
>   dbo.ImportError table.
>
> Your import was not completed. Please verify that the parameters of
>   your import are correct, and that the file you are trying to import is
>   accessible by our system and contains valid data. If you have any
>   questions, feel free to contact your Customer Support Representative.
>
> MID 1084844

Answer (score 1):

We're having the same problem. Have the file transfer activity before the import but we're still getting an error at the import step. It provides basically no information:

The error occurred during Step 5 of 6:

```
 5.1 ImportDefinition : Import_Sent
       Status: Error
       Start Time:  7/3/2014 10:30 AM Central Standard Time (no DST)
       Error Time:  7/3/2014 10:30 AM Central Standard Time (no DST)
```

Any information on anyone who got this to work would be amaaazing.

Comment: A Field to hold DateTime value can be created from a field holding Date value and a picklist field holding Time values. There are some consideration and limitation for this formula.

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is that you need a file transfer activity to run first before your import activity. This would move the file from your automation directory to the ET holding tank, where the Import Activity can pick it up.  Sometimes you can get it to work without a FT activity, but the file needs to be in the correct spot.